# Download de imagem somente pela sua URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho esta requisição:

```
var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';

$.post(exportUrl, d1, function(d1) {

});
```

Sendo que exportUrl+d1 se torna o *url* da minha imagem gerada pelo servidor. como faço pra continuar o processo e baixar ela ?

Tentei assim, mas não funcionou, ele apenas abriu uma aba e mostrou a imagem.

```
window.location.href=(exportUrl+d1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com puro javascript você pode realizar o download de uma imagem somente com a *URL*, mas antes precisa converte-la em arquivo e "jogar" dentro de uma html e forçar o download.

Entenda que o código abaixo roda uma função através do click, mas você pode roda a função dentro da seu *response*:

---

- > > Execulte o código abaixo aqui mesmo e clique em baixar

```js
function download_next(files) {
    //percorre o array de arquivos
  files.forEach(function (element, i, array) {
  
    //enquanto houver interação
  if (i >= files.length) {
   return;
  } 
   
    //cria um html <a>
  var a = document.createElement('a');
    
    //insere o arquivo no <a> criado
  a.href = files[i].download;
    
    //insere um atribute target
  a.target = '_parent';
    
    //criando download
  if ('download' in a) {
  a.download = files[i].filename;
  }
    
    //realizando click automático e baixando o arquivo após 1 segundo
  (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(a);
  if (a.click) {
   setTimeout(function() {
    a.click();
   }, 1000);
  } 
    
    //removendo o elemento
  a.parentNode.removeChild(a);  
 
  });
 }
```

```html
<a onclick="download_next([{ download:'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png'}])" style="background: red; color: #fff; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;">Baixar imagem</a>
```

Comment: aqui e em minha maquina nao esta realizando esse clique automatico

Comment: Deve ser algum erro de javascript, veja seu console, deixe ele aberto e tente novamente e veja se há algum erro. Ele ta baixando por aqui?

Comment: infelizmente nao esta baixando, e tambem nao aparece erro. no seu está baixando?

Comment: Note que você tem que se certificar que a url da imagem é *válida* e que ela está dentro disso: `[{download: 'http://imagem.png'}]` antes de passar na função. Você consegue baixar por aqui? No exemplo acima?

Comment: Lolipop somente clicando no botao (a)

Comment: Exatamente! Você tem que gerar a ação, rodar a função...Nesse exemplo você precisa clicar no botão.